houdini vex #include "custom library" is giving error
Im trying to reuse code, so i wrote a series of custom fucntion that i store in the project directory
But when i try to use trhen in the point wrangler node  it is giving me and error, and i cant understand why!
here is the code in the funcs.h file:
int summ(int a, int b){
   return a + b;
}

here is the code in the point wrangler node:
#include "$HIP/funcs.h";

int a = sum(1,2);
printf('%d',a);

and is giving me the follow error:
Syntax error, unexpected identifier, expecting ')'. (2,32) 

Here is the screenshoot to the error, hope it helps:
enter image description here
